How do I get Camel unit tests to work with JUnit's @TestInstance.LifeCycle.PER_CLASS?
I am developing unit tests for camel with JUnit. More specifically, I'm using the following library: org.apache.camel:camel-test-spring-junit5:4.7.0. The unit tests work fine when I have @TestInstance set to TestInstance.LifeCycle.PER_METHOD:
@SpringBootTest
@CamelSpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
@MockEndpoints("mllp:localhost:2575")
class HelloWorldMllpRouterUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    @EndpointInject("mock:mllp:localhost:2575")
    private MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

    @Test
    void whenSendBody_thenHelloWorldReceivedSuccessfully() {
        var expectedResponse = "Hello World!";
        mockEndpoint.returnReplyBody(ExpressionBuilder.bodyExpression(String.class, func -> expectedResponse));
        var resp = template.requestBody("mock:mllp:localhost:2575", "Some request body");
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResponse, resp);
    }
}


However, when I change @TestInstance such that it is set to TestInstance.LifeCycle.PER_CLASS (everything else being equal), I get the following error:

Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[]
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[]
at org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:45)
at org.apache.camel.support.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:691)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:591)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:182)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:372)
at com.myapp.HelloWorldMllpRouterUnitTest.whenSendBody_thenHelloWorldReceivedSuccessfully...

I need the PER_CLASS flag set because of existing unit tests using it. How do I get the test to work with the PER_CLASS flag set?

It seems like the @CamelSpringBootTest logic has a flag, "OptionNoStart", which when true prevents the camel context from starting through camelContext.start(). It seems like this flag is necessary to turn on before the integration tests run, in order to customize the Camel context. However, when the PER_CLASS flag is set, the "OptionNoStart" flag seemingly bugs out and doesn't turn off by the time the actual test is run. Therefore, the solution for me was to simply set this flag to false before all tests:
@SpringBootTest
@CamelSpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@MockEndpoints("mllp:localhost:2575")
class GreetingsMllpRouterUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    @EndpointInject("mock:mllp:localhost:2575")
    private MockEndpoint mock;

    @BeforeAll
    public void beforeAll() {
        SpringCamelContext.setNoStart(false);
        mock.start();
    }

    @Test
    void whenSendBody_thenGreetingReceivedSuccessfully() {
        var expectedResponse = "Hello World!";
        mock.returnReplyBody(ExpressionBuilder.bodyExpression(String.class, func -> expectedResponse));
        var resp = template.requestBody("mock:mllp:localhost:2575", "Hello Baeldung Readers 2!");
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResponse, resp);
    }
}

